# How can I pass back a jquery string from a js.erb in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have this code in a create.js.erb file which I expect back from a comment form I am subitting with `remote: true`

```
<div class="comment">
  <%= @comment.content %>
  <%= link_to "delete", comment_path(@comment, :deletecomment => 
      "delete"), remote: true, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You 
      sure?" } 
  %>
</div>
```

It seems that rails only processes valid jquery in this file. I can only make my code with the `''` around the html to make it a jquery string then send it back like this but funny enough the results when checking the data returned is a string with the single quotes as part of the string.

I then use `html = data.replace(/\'/g, "");` to remove the single quotes but is there a better way to do this?

For instance I cannot comment in the js.erb any notes I want to add in there when normally you can comment out the js.erb with `/*...*/`

I was thinking of removing the `remote: true` from the form I am using and doing a normal ajax call upon submit and setting `dataType` as `html` but still I think before this rails will have already corrupted my string.

Comment: It seems you are trying to return some html (the `<div…` stuff) rather than Javascript/JQuery. If that is true, why not just return the `<div… etc.` (without the single-quote wrapper) in a `create.html.erb` file?

Comment: Hi. Yes I thought of that but I do not want a full page reload..

Comment: I may have a work around for this though now. I am thinking of using the micropopst id for the comments container that way I have a hold on a element when my code gets back to the page. I can prepend the comment to the container. My code was a little obscure anyway I will delete this post.

Comment: @LeeEather it would be better if you can make a seperate partial of code that you are sending back from `create.js.erb` and just refresh that code in a div wherever you want. i can explain it in detail answer if you need.

Comment: Yes this is what I realised I am better targeting a div on the page the problem is they all have same .class but I am going to add the micropost.id into the div class then retrieve that id server side and do as you said eg `$('<%= comment.micropost.id %>').prepend(' render partial here...');` in js.erb

Comment: @LeeEather you can see the answer and let me if its helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a partial :-
_example_partial.html.erb

```
<div class="comment">
   <%= comment.content %>
   <%= link_to "delete", comment_path(comment, :deletecomment => "delete"),remote: true, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
</div>
```

and in `create.js.erb`

```
$("#id_of_div_where_the_partial_will_append").append("<%= j render 'example_partial', comment: @comment%>");
```